# Type declaration for decorated method in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mobx

I am trying to use Mobx library in my React project using TypeScript. Assuming "experimentalDecorators" is enabled in tsconfig.json.

In Mobx, the observable decorator takes value (in below case string[]) and returns an observable value (in this case IObservableArray). It means that `store.todos` in below is actually IObservableArray not String[].

However, TSC does not seem to check derived value of decorated property and still thinks `todos` is string[].

```
class TodoStore {
    @observable public todos = ["buy milk", "buy eggs"];
}
const store = TodoStore;
store.todos.replace([]);  // <- error as replace comes from IObservableArray
```

Is there a way to configure TypeScript to correctly determines the derived value type of decorator function that changes value type?

Below equivalent code without @ notation gives me what I want but wondering if there is a way to use decorator syntax (@decolator) to do the same.

```
class Store {
    public todos = observable(["buy milk", "buy eggs"]);
}
```